# How could I use an object's method calling the thread instance of it?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am currently writing a server for a multiplayer game. The main class of the server is as follows:

```
public final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Turtle.class.getName());
public boolean isStopped = true;
public static Turtle serverInstance;
public NetworkHandler networkHandler;

protected InetAddress ip;
protected int port;

public Turtle(InetAddress ip, int port){
    this.ip = ip;
    this.port = port;

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    serverInstance = new Thread(new Turtle(NetworkHandler.getipByName("0.0.0.0"), 19132));
    serverInstance.start();
}

public void run() {
    logger.info("Starting Turtle...");
    isStopped = false;
    logger.info("Initializing Networking.");
    networkHandler = new NetworkHandler(ip, port);
    networkHandler.start();
    logger.info("Done!");
}

public NetworkHandler getNetworkHandler(){
    return networkHandler;
}

public static Thread getServer(){
    return serverInstance;
}

public static String getMOTD(){
    return "MCCPP;MINECON;[0/20] Turtle Test Server";
}

public Logger getLogger(){
    return logger;
}

public void stop(){
    logger.info("Turtle is stopping.");
    networkHandler.stahp();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

This class itself is a Runnable. As you can see, I *attempt* to start the server by setting the static serverInstance to an instance of the server in a thread, then by calling the start method. However, this does not work, because serverInstance requires the Turtle object (the name of this class). I cannot change this to Thread, because other parts of the program require use of methods from Turtle through this instance, and changing serverInstance to Thread wouldn't let me access any methods of the class.

So, the question is, how do I set serverInstance as this thread, and also retain access to all of Turtle's methods from serverInstance?

Sorry if this was a bit confusing. It's a little jumbled in my head too, and I may have had some trouble getting this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?:

```
public static Turtle globalTurtle;
public static Thread serverInstance;

public static void main(String[] args){
    globalTurtle = new Turtle(NetworkHandler.getipByName("0.0.0.0"), 19132);
    serverInstance = new Thread(globalTurtle);
    serverInstance.start();
}
```

(with all the other lines as well...)

Comment: Yes, thank you! :) I was thinking that using the raw class may not produce the same results as the thread...apparently I was wrong. Thanks again!